# Serialization one class object, and deserialize it as another class

Tags: java, serialization

Do everybody know if in Java exist possibility to serialize MyClass object and deserialize it as MyAnotherClass object?

MyClass object has fields as below:

```
public class MyClass implements Serializable {

 private String text;
 private int number;
 private String abbrv;

}
```

And MyAnotherClass :

```
public class MyClass implements Serializable {

 private String text;
 private int number;
 private String abbrv;
 private boolean b; 
 private List<String> myList;

}
```

If it's possible, please tell me how to do that.

Comment: Frying a fish but serving as chicken, bad ;-)

Comment: And what values do you expect the new instance members to have? No

Comment: I expect null values for example. 
I know, it kind of serialization is weird, but I need it in my system.

Answer (score 0):

You can if the originally serialized object's class contains a

```
private Object readResolve()
```

method, or if it contained a

```
private Object writeReplace()
```

method prior to serialization, or if you use a trusted subclass of ObjectInputStream that suitably overrides resolveObject(), or a trusted subclass of ObjectOutputStream that overrides replaceObject().

Comment: Thanks for your answer. What should I put in readResolve/writeReplace methods? Just simple cast?

Comment: That wouldn't make sense, would it? Casting between your two classes won't work, as they aren't related by inheritance. You would have to return an instance of the other class.